# CPU Load Issue (Magnolia-5.3.3 Jackrabbit-2.8.0)

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, magnolia, jelastic

Project use DAM as storage of many mp3 for licensing (plan more then 750Gb)
We upload mp3 and metadata by Rest.
Server: CPU 2 GHz, mem 1.2 Gb available for java 64bit 1.7.0_51-b13 (jelastic), DB - MySQL

We upload 30 Gb of mp3. After that suddenly magnolia loads all CPU resource - 100%.
Anything errors or warnings about it are in logs. Magnolia works but very slow.
Restart don't helped.

May be after repair all workspace repositories server started and worked - I don't sure. DAM workspace loaded more then 1.5 hour at first time and more then 5-10 or 30 min next.

But after uploading next 20 Gb we have got the same troubles. Repair of repositories don't helped.

For repair repositories changed in each workspace.xml next param:

```
<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager">
....
<param name="consistencyCheck" value="true" />
<param name="consistencyFix" value="true" />
</PersistenceManager>
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
...
      <param name="forceConsistencyCheck" value="true"/>
      <param name="autoRepair" value="true"/>
<param name="onWorkspaceInconsistency" value="log"/>
```

Comment: I recommend to ask your hosting provider for help with this issue.
Also, it will be very helpful look at application server logs, to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. But "anything errors or warnings" - all logger in DEBUG. In server terminal "ps aux" or "top" show me: java (tomcat) process loads CPU.

Comment: I ran magnolia on new repository folder and uploaded 10 Gb - all ok (while).

Comment: Consider changing DAM asset provider to other than JackRabbit, e.g. file system. Documentation: [Configuration](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Digital+Asset+Management+module#DigitalAssetManagementmodule-Assetprovidersandrenderers) and [asset provider API](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/DAM+API#DAMAPI-AssetProvider). You can extend existing JCR API to store files not in JCR but in filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess issue is the content type you are uploading - mp3 is being indexed (off the queue) by JackRabbit. That's also why restart doesn't help as repo knows those files are still not indexed and continues to work on them. Solution should be to change indexing configuration to switch off indexing of those files. See [Search Index](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Search#Search-Indexing) and [Full text parsing](http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Concept+-+Explicit+Full+Text+Parsing+Configuration) for more details.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks. I launched on the failed repository with rebuilding of index for DAM workspace. Magnolia-cms works.